# Explanation on [ (n) ] or [ fields ] [ (p) ] in PostgreSQL docs

Tags: postgresql, documentation

I'm reading through the PostgreSQL docs and didn't find examples or explanations on the syntax used there. For example [on the documentation page for data types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype.html) you find a table having `[ (n) ]` and similar. Could somebody please explain or provide examples what all of those for me crypting symbols mean?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax is described in the [Conventions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/notation.html) page of the manual.

For instance, `[(n)]` means that *optionally* there is a numeric value in parentheses.